# unity particle doen't play second time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I have a particle system defined in my game objects. When I call `Play` it plays (it plays for 5 seconds by design). when I call `Play` again nothing happens. I tried  to call `Stop` and `Clear` before recalling `Play` but that didn't help.

Can particle systems play more than once?

My code is in this method, which is called when a button is clicked.

```
public void PlayEffect() 
{ 
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) 
    { 
        NextItemEffectsP[i].Stop(); 
        NextItemEffectsP[i].Clear(); 
        NextItemEffectsP[i].Play(); 
    } 
}
```

`NextItemEffectsP` is an array that contains particles that I populate in the editor

Comment: Please post some code so that we'll be able to see how to help you. Also, what language is your code in?

Comment: This code in this method. Tthe method called when a button clicked.  
public void PlayEffect()
 {
  for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    NextItemEffectsP[i].Stop();
    NextItemEffectsP[i].Clear();
    NextItemEffectsP[i].Play();
    
  }
 }

NextItemEffectsP is an array that contains particles that I populate in the editor

Comment: I found the issue.  The duration of the particle is 2 second.  if I call play after 2 second nothing happen.  Should I create new instance everytime I need to start a particle after the 2 second?  how can I kn ow when the particle finish work so I can destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

You should rework how your bullet works. Have some code on the bullet Prefab to control when it gets destroyed.

```
private float fuse = 1.0;
private float selfDestructTimer;

void Awake() {
    // Time.time will give you the current time.
    selfDestructTimer = Time.time + fuse;
}

void Update() {
    if (selfDestructTimer > 0.0 && selfDestructTimer < Time.time) {
        // gameObject refers to the current object
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Then with that control set up, you'll always just create new bullets whenever the fire button is pressed.